# make div unresponsive but not affecting parent div in foundation zurb

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make my div(widget) not responsive, however I do not want to affect the parent div it's sitting on, as the parent div(the div with the class="medium-4 columns") needs to be responsive. My Code:

```
    <div class="medium-4 columns sidebar">
        <div class="widget">
            <img src="img/mail-icon.png">
            <span class="mail-label">What is an e-bill?</span>
            <p>
                Some text is attached here
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need the class widget to be not responsive. Is there a way I can make it so without removing the "medium-4 columns" class

Comment: What do you mean by `make div unresponsive`? The parent has a variable  width, hence if the children have a fixed width, they'll break the parent on lower screens.

Comment: @HashemQolami Is there a way that the  child div wont move at all? Or do I need to really remove the responsiveness of the parent altogether without affecting the column width?

Comment: This problem can not be resolved unless the sufficient information is given. Please provide a fiddle or sample to demonstrate the issue in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want your image not to be responsive, I suggest you add `style="max-width:none;"` like this :

```
<img src="img/mail-icon.png" style="max-width:none;">
```